# BigQuery - Rebuild/Refresh a table with new column data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with close to 40 columns(including 3 structs) which contains more than 1 TB of data. Now I need to add a new column to that table and refresh complete table data to reflect values to new column.

Could you please help me on what is the best/optimized way to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new fields when editing the schema as below: [image: bq-new-fields]

After that, you can update the table with the new data

Comment: Sorry, my question was what is best way to process the data after adding a new column